# cumulative sum until a certain value

Tags: r

I have some data from a school year that I am working with. The variables are SchoolYear, Aug, Sep, Oct, ..., May, June where each month corresponds to th number of participants for that month. I need to sum the months until there is missing info, in this case identified by a 0. I have tried

```
yeardf <-within(yeardf,{
  Max_enroll<-cummax(Sep)
  Enroll_To_Date<-cumsum(Sep)
}
)

1973-74,0,0,4,2,14,26,22,8,0,99,
1974-75,0,0,4,26,10,23,10,14,0,91,
```

while putting a condition of Sep>0 on the Enroll_To_Date line but have not been succesfull.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including some data to help others run your code. Just turn the last two lines into valid R code for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your data as lists and data frame:

```
> row1 <- c("1973-74",0,0,4,2,14,26,22,8,0,99)
> row2 <- c("1974-75",0,0,4,26,10,23,10,14,0,91)
> df <- rbind(row1,row2)
```

Cumulative sums of `row1` can be found like this, and it looks like you want to capture the 76 (where it hits a zero):

```
> (z <- cumsum(row1[2:length(row1)]))
 [1]   0   0   4   6  20  46  68  76  76 175
```

Here's one way to get it. First find the spot in the list that has the value:

```
> which(duplicated(lead(cumsum(row1[2:length(row1)]))))
[1] 8
```

And then look up the cumulative sum at that value:

```
> z[which(duplicated(lead(cumsum(row1[2:length(row1)]))))]
[1] 76
```

So here's the calculation for your `row2`:

```
> z <- cumsum(row2[2:length(row2)])
> z[which(duplicated(lead(cumsum(row2[2:length(row2)]))))]
[1] 87
```

And if you want to do a lot of them, like in the data frame `df`, chain them together in a function and use `apply` over all the rows (`1`) of your data frame:

```
> apply(df,1,function(x) cumsum(x[2:length(x)])[which(duplicated(lead(cumsum(x[2:length(x)]))))])
row1 row2 
  76   87
```